# Parse.com cloud code to total after saveall

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse.com class, called `Node`, which contains a number column called `cost`.

My client app allows for creation of multiple nodes at once, which get saved to Parse using a SaveAll call.

I then have another class `NodeTotals` which will contain the total of all `cost` grouped according a certain criteria.

I am trying to implement an **efficient** method to do the totals in cloud code. My initial approach was to have an `AfterSave` function (on `Node`) that:

- queries all existing `Node` rows that meet my criteria
- sums the `cost` on the returned results
- queries to see if a `NodeTotal` entry exists, updates the total if yes, or creates a new entry if not

But this approach is not optimal I fear - for at least the following 2 reasons:

1. performing all these queries on every `Node` save cant be good
2. if a bunch of new `Node` objects are created by the client, which then does a SaveAll, multiple instances of my AfterSave function get called in parallel - each one thinks that there are no existing `NodeTotal` entries, so creates a new one (third point above) - resulting in more than one `NodeTotal` row being created where there really should be only one

I am pretty sure there must be a better way of doing what I am trying to do - just need some bright spark to point it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who comes across this, i ended up doing the following :

in order to address issue 1) I made sure that the `Node Total` was created at the point in time that the `Node` was created - thereby eliminating the need to query for existence at time of update every time

for issue 2) is used the Parse `Object.Increment` function to ensure atomic operation